# How to hide addon domains folder paths from search results

Tags: web-hosting, domain-forwarding, search-results, add-on-domain

I have a hosting account with domain.com and we are hosting about 5 different websites. I have 5 folders in the hosting account each one with a unique folder name and of course 5 different domains assigned to each of those folders. Each site works but sadly on the main domain the folder names are visible in the Google search results, for example:

[image: Example of folders being incorrectly indexed in Google Search Results]

*Question(s):*

- *How can this be resolved?*
- *How can this be prevented?*

Comment: Hi @John you should mark the correct answer or post the correct one to help the community move on

Answer (score 3):

This is just another case of two or more URLs pulling up the same content. You have two ways you can handle this:

1. Do a [301 redirect](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php) from the URLs you do **not** want to show in the search results to the one that you **do** want to show.
2. Use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.12345.com/example.html" />`

Answer (score 1):

Without more info about your hosting situation i am unsure if this would work, but here is a stack that will try to force redirect-canonicalize all host/sub/domain/ip instances into `http://www.addon-domain.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.123\.123\.123 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.123\.123\.123\.123 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^d5151150\.host-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.d5151150\.host-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon-domain\.my-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.addon-domain\.my-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www\.addon-domain\.com/$1" [R=301,L]
```

If you encounter the platform install path showing once the domain is redirect-canonicalized, then this is a different issue -- you should use a rewrite for that or make the addon (and util sub) "live" in the install folder of said platform.